# This is a troll, right?

Tags: support, specific-answer

Looking at [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/48912/4495), I can't help but notice that they pretend to not know what the name of the movie is (even though they have the name and the year correct) and to pretend they're not interested in science fiction, even though they signed up for this site especially to answer this question! Oh, and the answer is wrong.

Now normally I would give someone the benefit of the doubt, but they haven't returned for a week. I don't believe they're sincere.

Comment: Are you talking about an answer or the question?

Comment: @oncer12_shawn The answer by Spike, but the matter is moot, as it was deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, "spike" has been coming on for about a week now, periodically posting fatuous questions and generally being a nuisance. I gather they've been creating multiple accounts after getting booted.